# Search Similar String using vba in same column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search similar string which exist under same column from a input excel file and group them together and perform some calculation.

Example say : I have input file named : Predictions

```
FUND_NAME   CLASS_NAME  FUND_CODE    CASHFLOW_IN_FUND_CURRENCY 
AA              BB              SSIS         19200
VV              DD              SPIS         16200
QQ              NN              BNIS         15830
CC              DJ              SSIS         -6300
```

I want a code in VBA which should combine Similar Fund_Codes together and perform some logical calculations on CASHFLOW_IN_FUND_CURRENCY .

Say When 1st nd 4th row has same fund code (SSIS) then I need to ABS(sum(19200-6300))

I know the logic for calculations ,but couldn't find the logic to group the fund_code within same worksheet and same column.

I had tried the Rachels method fuzzy logic in stack overlow but it didn't work ,

I also tried the below code and it did not work .

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRANS")
    Dim rngFundCode As Range

    lRow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngFundCode = Range("C:C")

    For i = 2 To lRow
        Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), rngFundCode, 2, False)
    Next i
```

Could anyone ,let me know how to group the similr string within same column and prform some logic calculation on the other column

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRANS")
    Dim rngFundCode As Range

    lRow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngFundCode = Range("C:C")

    For i = 2 To lRow
        Cells(i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), rngFundCode, 2, False)
    Next i
```

I want a code in VBA which should combine Similar Fund_Codes together and perform some logical calculations on CASHFLOW_IN_FUND_CURRENCY .

Say When 1st nd 4th row has same fund code (SSIS) then I need to ABS(sum(19200-6300))

Comment: If I have understood you correctly.... You can use a formula `=ABS(SUMIF($C$2:$C$1000,C2,$D$2:$D$1000))` where `C` is `FUND_CODE` and `D` is `CASHFLOW_IN_FUND_CURRENCY`.  **OR** You can also sort data on `FUND_CODE` and then do the calculations in VBA? **OR** You can store the data in an array and create a unique collection of  `FUND_CODE` and then perform calculation in the array? Many ways to skin a cat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a class and got the values as a collection from the input file and got this resolved.

Function CalculateReport() As Boolean

```
Dim bOutput As Boolean: bOutput = False
Dim colPrediction As Collection
Dim objPred As clsPrediction
Dim shtPred As Worksheet
Dim colFunds As New Collection

On Error GoTo ErrorAccessingFile
Set shtPred = g_colInputFiles("txtPredictions").GetSheets(1).GetSheet
On Error GoTo 0

'Get Data from Input Files
Set colPrediction = GetPredictionData(shtPred)
Dim col As Collection

'Split the data by FundCode
For Each objPred In colPrediction
    If ItemIsInCollection(colFunds, objPred.Fund_Code) Then
        Set col = colFunds(objPred.Fund_Code)
        col.Add objPred, objPred.getKey
    Else
        Set col = New Collection
        col.Add objPred, objPred.getKey
        colFunds.Add col, objPred.Fund_Code
    End If
Next objPred

For Each col In colFunds
    If col.Count > 1 Then
        'Apply Formula

    End If
Next col
```